# Animated underline hover effect for text-wrapped elements

Tags: html, css

I was browsing https://2019.stateofcss.com/ and noticed the nice underline hover animation they have for the links. What's interesting though is how they've disabled the underline hover effect when the text inside an `<a>` tag wraps and spans multiple lines.

How did they go about disabling the underline hover effect only when the text wraps?

There doesn't *seem* to be any inlined or additional class that gets applied, and the CSS rules appear to be the same regardless whether or not the text is wrapped.

Anyone have any ideas how they implemented this magic?

Comment: they are not disabling it, it's a drawback of their method. It cannot work with multiple line

Comment: Which one has the text wrapping and the effect disabled ?

Comment: @sscotti For the link `download the raw JSON data for this survey` - if you shrink the viewport width down until it wraps - the underline effect disappears on hover. However, it appears when its a single line.

Comment: @Temani Afif I think is correct.  They have a transform set up with a::before, and it looks like that breaks when the text wraps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are correct - that website isn't handling the case when links were being underlined.

However - I have found an alternative solution that DOES handle the multiline underline animation. They're setting a background image to the element and applying the same principles

https://codepen.io/christiancroser/pen/xqrLBm

```
$color-on-light: black;
$underline-width: 2px;

color: $color-on-light;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 0% 100%;
background-position: bottom right;
transition: background-size 0.15s;
padding-bottom: $underline-width;
background-image: linear-gradient(
    transparent calc(100% - #{$underline-width}),
    $color-on-light $underline-width
);

&.on-dark {
    $color-on-dark: white;

    color: $color-on-dark;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        transparent calc(100% - #{$underline-width}),
        $color-on-dark $underline-width
    );
}

&:hover {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: bottom left;
}
```